# What is an alternative to the negative lookbehind (that's not implemented) in CTRE?

Tags: c++, regex, regex-lookarounds, ctre

I'm trying to match a part of a string that surrounds a word inside of it.
For example: `[This]`. I would like to match `[This]`, but only when the character before it is not a backslash, so for example, not this `\[This]`.

```cpp
for (auto match: ctre::range<R"((((?<!\\))\[[^\]]*\])">(input)) {
   // you can use match.str() here
}
```

Usually the regex I would use is this:

```
(((?<!\\))\[[^\]]*\])
```

..but, according to [this](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions/issues/105#issuecomment-666316539) comment and the received `ctre::problem_at_position<5>`, it seems that it's not supported in CTRE as of today.

Is there a way to do what I want to do even though it's not implemented?

Comment: What about `[^\\](\[[^\]]*\])`?

Comment: Can the backslash itself be escaped with a backslash, like `\\[This]`? Can the closing bracket be escaped, like `[String with \[escaped\] brackets]`? It's possible to write a regex to deal with all this, but at this point I'd write a simple hand-coded parser.

Comment: @horcrux this seems to only match things like `abcde[This]abce` meaning it needs to have a character before it (that isn't `\`). I need it to match `[This]` too, with the only exception being `\[This]`.

Comment: Ok then [`(?:^|[^\\])(\[[^\]]*\])`](https://regex101.com/r/0gzhn2/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is the following:

```
(?:^|[^\\])(\[[^\]]*\])
```

where:

- `(?:^|[^\\])` is a non-capturing group that uses alternation (`|`) for choosing between `^` (the beginning of the string) or `[^\\]` (any character that is not a backslash).
- `(\[[^\]]*\])` captures the desired pattern.